Deleting table with metadata corruption on SQL Server
We are trying to recover from an event and struggling with some issues that have been created within our database. One of our tables (Users) seems to have gotten corrupted somehow, as we get this message anytime we touch the table:

No catalog entry found for partition ID 72057594068664320 in database 7. 
The metadata is inconsistent. 
Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption.

We tried to load from an old mdf file but got the same message. Our path forward seems to be to delete the user table and rebuild it with data from our test database. However, I can't drop the table from our live database because I still receive the message above. I ran DBCC CHECKTABLE and got this message:

Could not find an entry for table or index with partition ID 
72057594068664320 in database 8. This error can occur if a stored 
procedure references a dropped table, or metadata is corrupted. 
Drop and re-create the stored procedure, or execute DBCC CHECKDB.

Is there anything I can do to drop the existing table that seems to be corrupted?

Typically when a database has metadata or system structure corruption and no backups is to create a new database with a known good structure and migrate the data.
There is also a lack of actual CheckDB output here so who knows how insidious the corruption is at this point. There may be hackish ways of fixing it but the database would essentially be unsupportable at that point and migrating to a new known good database would still be the plan.
